# Can't get fields on display.ejs. I only get empty rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Here is my controller. I can get data that is already in the database but problem is that data cant appear in my view.

```
const Comment = require('../models/comments.js');

exports.getComments = (req, res, next) =>{
    Comment.fetchAll()
        .then(rows => {
            res.render('display', {
                data: rows,
            });
            console.log(rows)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

And here is my view

```
 <% if(data.length > 0) { %>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Comment</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) { %>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><%= (i+1) %></th>
                    <td><%= data[i].name%></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].email%></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].comment%></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <% } %>
        
        <!-- if result is empty -->
        <% if(!data.length) { %>
           <p class="text-center">No comments found!</p> 
        <% } %>
```

I don't know why I'm getting empty fields in the view because when i `console.log(rows)` I get data.

Comment: What's the content of data?

Comment: {
      name: 'maseno',
      email: 'maseno@gmail.com',
      comment: 'I love maseno students'
    },

Comment: i expect that data in my view

Comment: then data is not an array

Comment: I passed data  as an array now i get data in my views. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem was my view was expecting an array `[rows]` . So I had to pass an array as callback.

```
exports.getComments = (req, res, next) =>{
    Comment.fetchAll()
        .then(([rows]) => {
            res.render('display', {
                data: rows,
            });
            console.log(rows)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```